# Where should "only" be in the sentence: " She died at age 21"?

Tags: expressions, adverb-placement

I wrote an essay and in one sentence:

> "She died [only] at [only] age [only] 21"

I don't know where the adverb "only" should be. Can someone help me?

Comment: "She died at the age of only 21" Putting _only_ directly before the number emphasises that it was a tragically early age.

Comment: And on the other hand, "She died only at age 21" would imply that it was a tragically, or at least surprisingly, *late* age - cf. "He understood it *only* when I explained it for the third time". Isn't English fun?

Comment: @Kate Bunting: Thank you Kate : )

Comment: @Maciej Stachowski: it is haha. Thanks a lot Maciej: ))

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, "only" can go anywhere.

It really depends on what one is trying to say.
A general rule of thumb is that if you say the sentence without the "only", but in a surprised way (She died at age 21!!) the word you naturally stress is the one that "only" should go in front of.

Dying is something one does only once, so a better example would be visiting Paris.

| Sentence | Possible Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| Only *she* visited Paris at age 21. | Her friends waited until about 25. |
| She only *visited* Paris at age 21. | She later moved there at 25. |
| She visited only *Paris* at age 21. | She didn't visit anywhere else that year. |
| She visited Paris only *at* age 21. | She never visited Paris at any other age. |
| She visited Paris at only *age* 21. | She visited Paris much younger than her friends. |
| She visited Paris at age only *21*. | She visited Paris at a relatively young age. |

Some of these are very similar in meaning, but with different verbs the minor differences could become more significant.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the rule clearly and providing the useful examples to help me understand. I appreciate your help!!